# Disable bind 9.3.6 hostname disclosure

Tags: security, bind, hostname

I've bind 9.3.6.

How can I disable hostname disclosure ?

Issue link http://www.iss.net/security_center/reference/vuln/bind-hostname-disclosure.htm

Thanks.

Comment: The document you link to says `There is no remedy as of December 18, 2010`

Comment: @Iain even though that message was updated 2 days ago, and remains unchanged, it is _still_ incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hide ***hostname*** and ***version*** this way:

```
# /etc/named.conf
options {
    // hide bind info
    hostname "unknown";
    version "unknown";
}
```

Hostname querying example:

```
[vitalie@silver ~]$ dig @ns1.kappa.ro hostname.bind chaos txt

; <<>> DiG 9.3.6-P1-RedHat-9.3.6-4.P1.el5_5.3 <<>> @ns1.kappa.ro hostname.bind chaos txt
; (1 server found)
;; global options:  printcmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 46430
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;hostname.bind.                 CH      TXT

;; ANSWER SECTION:
hostname.bind.          0       CH      TXT     "linux.kappa.ro"

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
hostname.bind.          0       CH      NS      hostname.bind.

;; Query time: 6 msec
;; SERVER: 194.102.255.3#53(194.102.255.3)
;; WHEN: Wed Jan  5 15:08:14 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 72
```

Comment: version "unknown" will return the string "unknown".  version "none" will actually disable the feature.

Comment: In ubuntu 12/14 and debian 8 config file is in : /etc/bind/named.conf.options

Answer (score 6):

"There is no remedy as of December 18, 2010." **Wrong, so very wrong.** *There has been a fix since February 2006* (at least). Put this in your BIND config (it probably is there already):

```
options {
  version "none";
}
```

Let me "craft" this "special" query (don't attempt this at home):

```
$ nslookup -q=txt -class=CHAOS authors.bind. localhost
Server:         localhost
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

*** Can't find authors.bind.: No answer
```

For more info on securing BIND have a look at http://www.cymru.com/Documents/secure-bind-template.html

Comment: To be clear... the string "none" is special in that it disables the feature.  This does not happen if you set it to "unknown" or anything else.

Comment: Is there a way to disable `hostname.bind` query as well?

Answer (score 2):

You can disable hostname.bind by putting this in named.conf (valid in BIND 9.9 that I use):

```
options {  
  hostname none;  
}
```